# Can a LyX/LaTeX file be too large to create a PDF?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, lyx

I've been working on my bachelors thesis in LyX for about a month without encountering any problems and today, all of a sudden, when creating a PDF LyX just loads indefinitely and even asks me at some point if I want to stop the PDF creating since it takes such a long time. Am I doing something wrong? I have about 100 pages and the PDFs I created lately have been around 100 mb large since they hold very high res images and a lot of them.

Comment: So I found out by now that LyX for some reason converts my images into eps files and tries to load them I think? Problem being that these files range from 1 mb to 20 mb in size. Can I somehow tell LyX to use my jpegs and pngs instead?

Comment: I think you can tell LyX to do that by modifying the converters. See e.g., Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters. For more information, read through Help > Customization. If nothing else works, maybe just convert the PDFs to raster images on your own and input those to LyX directly?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is struggling with the "convert" functionality usage in Lyx, this is some additional info:

Initially I struggled to make eps to load and be displayed on screen as well as to get it exported to PDF file. I saw that the Lyx latest install had already all "convert blah-blah $$ii $$o" commands predefined and it was still not working.

Here is what worked for me:

```
sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlout
```

Here there are two parts -

a) imagemagick needs to be installed on the machine as it provides most of the converters. Following command on terminal would check if imagemagick is installed or not on your system.

```
identify -version
```

b) Imagemagick tools should be "allowed" to run - "convert" being one of those. You need to relax some default security policies for that. That is what the above renaming of the policy file does. Detailed information is given in [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081907/746843) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1081895/746843) on ubuntu forum.

Note - This security policy relaxation is not recommended for web-server machines. Only desktop users may take the risk.